# Scala version mismatch on Amazon EMR Flink

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

Trying to run Flink(v 1.7.0) job on Amazon EMR Flink(5.21.0). 
I get the exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
```

The exception looks like SCALA version issue. I found flink libraries there is SCALA 2.11 and my job build using 2.12. Flink 1.7.0 supports SCALA 2.12.

The question is, how do I get Amazon EMR supporting SCALA 2.12 instead of 2.11? or Is there any better solution other my code going back 2.11.

Answer (score 0):

EMR is using Flink 1.6.1, I believe. So that's the version you'd want to build your Flink workflow against.

Comment: Current EMR uses Flink 1.7.0. I can't go back on Flink version because some of the featured we need don't have there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a description [here in the docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/deployment/aws.html#custom-emr-installation) of how to manually install whatever version of Flink you want to use with EMR.

Comment: I kind of looked at these docs before, I was thinking there is some kind of configuration which will help to move to SCALA 2.12 on cluster creation. May be that would be a nice feature to add.